# Delete Numeration Lines from Subtitle

Tags: regex

I have this subtitle text with many many lines. 
Before *times and text* i have *numeration* (1,2,3,4,5...111 numbers):

*Legend:*

```
1 = numeration
2 = numeration
00:14:xx:xx = times
quando a te... = text
```

*text example:*

```
1
00:14:38,511 --> 00:14:45,747
quando a te venne il Salvatore,

2
00:14:55,595 --> 00:15:06,699
...volle da te prendere il battesimo,...
ma il prete rifiuto

10
00:15:16,082 --> 00:15:27,050
e si consacrò al martirio,

213
00:15:34,467 --> 00:15:46,174
ci diede un pegno di salvezza:
ecco! ci siamo andiamo a ubriarci
```

**i want delete *numeration* lines:**

```
1
2
10
213
```

***this should be the end result:***

```
00:14:38,511 --> 00:14:45,747
quando a te venne il Salvatore,

00:14:55,595 --> 00:15:06,699
...volle da te prendere il battesimo,...
ma il prete rifiuto

00:15:16,082 --> 00:15:27,050
e si consacrò al martirio,

00:15:34,467 --> 00:15:46,174
ci diede un pegno di salvezza:
ecco! ci siamo andiamo a ubriarci
```

Comment: Typically you don't just use "regex" on it's own, but through a program like `grep` or in some programming language. In `grep`, you use the argument `-v` to *invert* the selection -- print out non-matching lines.

Comment: i se windows 7, i use notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Search: `(?m)^\d+$[\r\n]+`
- Replace: empty string

In engines that don't support inline modifiers such as `(?m)`, you'll usually add the `m` flag at the end of the pattern, like so:

```
/^\d+$[\r\n]+/m
```

**Explanation**

- `(?m)` turns on multi-line mode, allowing `^` and `$` to match on each line
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `\d+` matches digits
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string
- `[\r\n]+` matches line breaks
- We replace with the empty string

Comment: `you can accept answers in 5 minutes` give me stackoverflow..i must wait 4 minute, please patience, you were faster than the system..

Answer (score 1):

You can simply just use the following:

```
Find: ^\d+\s+
Replace:
         ^ empty
```

Explanation:

```
^       # the beginning of the string
\d+     # digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
\s+     # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
```

Comment: it works and is very simple, thank you, but zx81 give me aswer before you, sorry but stackoverflow don't accept 2 best answers..